# Topological order at finite temperature

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, monoidal-categories, higher-category-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

For the past few decades the study of so-called topological orders has remained an active area of research. By definition (following the motivation section of [this recent invitation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.05565.pdf) to the subject, for the sake of anchoring ourselves to a common reference point), a **topological order** is a gapped quantum liquid without symmetry, where a gapped quantum liquid is a specific type of quantum phase, which itself is an equivalence class of a quantum state of matter *at zero temperature*. Fairly recently, these [were classified](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.06663) in terms of mildly dualizable, monoidal, Karoubi-complete n-categories with trivial center.

In the physics literature, however, there is some (admittedly not much) discussion of topological order at *finite temperature*, and so I was wondering: is there anything known on the mathematical side about these (in terms of higher categories)?

(Or, I suppose, another way of asking the same thing: is there a clear way in which the zero temperature condition is encoded within the higher categorical language of Johnson-Freyd’s classification scheme?)